# ansible-playbook extra vars passing from command line

Tags: linux, variables, ansible

My playbook looks like:

```
---

- name: Install and configure AD authentication
  hosts: test
   become: yes
   become_user: root

  vars:
    hostname: "{{ host_name }}"


  vars_prompt:
    - name: "bind_password"
      prompt: "Password for xxx.local\\user"
      private: yes

  tasks:

    - name: Ansible prompt example.
      debug:
        msg: "{{ bind_password }}"

    - name: Ansible prompt example.
      debug:
        msg: "{{ host_name }}"
```

and i am using below command to pass the variable 
     ansible-playbook hostname_set.yml --extra-vars "host_name= 'xxx.xxx.local'"

but i am not getting exact variable value what i am using for setting up hostname.

```
Password for xxx.xxx\user:
PLAY [Install and configure AD authentication] 
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
 ok: [x.x.x.x]
TASK [Ansible prompt example.] 
     ok: [x.x.x.x] => {
        "msg": "wel"
}
TASK [Ansible prompt example.] 
ok: [x.x.x.x] => {
    "msg": ""
}
 TASK [Setup the hostname] 
 changed: [x.x.x.x]
 PLAY RECAP 
 x.x.x.x              : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    
 skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Please refrain from pasting images to show command output. Paste the output in a code block instead. This is way easier to read (at leas for my old eyes), copypastable if needed and indexable by SO internal or external search engines.

Note that in this specific case, your MCVE could have been reduced to a single command line: `ansible localhost -e "host_name= 'xxx.xxx.local'" -m debug -a msg="{{host_name}}"` (which returns the same result as above and expected one when removing the extra space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space in your command line that ruins how ansible is interpreting the extra vars. Just remove it:

`--extra-vars "host_name='xxx.xxx.local'"`

Note that you don't even need all those quotes. The following should also work as expected:

`--extra-vars host_name=xxx.xxx.local`